# perl replace with %d

Tags: regex, perl

I am a newbie to Perl. I am trying to replace a string with '-S%d' string.
But in the output I see -S0 instead of -S%d. How to deal with that?
Code kind of looks like this:

```
$test =~ s/-S1234/-S%d/;
```

For further clarification -

```
$test = 'This_is_StackOverflow-S11152017'
```

I wish to get following output -

```
'This_is_StackOverflow-S%d'
```

Comment: Numbers are detected with `\d`, so multiple digits is `\d+` (`+` being the modifier for "one or more").

Comment: What is `$test` before the substitution? What's the desired output?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question needs a bit more detail, please provide the sample input in `$test` and the full output you're receiving, and you should always format your code with the available markdown. Please check this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Works fine for me: https://ideone.com/m2UiSX

Comment: It sounds like you're doing `printf $test;` instead of `print $test;`. `%d` is a `printf` format operator, and it gets replaced with an argument to `printf`, which defaults to `0`.

Comment: That is correct, Barmar. I am doing printf. Is there anyway to use printf and still get %d string in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution works as intended, the problem is most likely with how you're printing it. You should do:

```
print "$test\n";
```

or:

```
printf "%s\n", $test;
```

The output you're getting would result if you did:

```
printf $test;
```

The first argument to `printf` is a format string, and `%d` is for formatting an integer argument. With no corresponding argument, it defaults to `0`.

Comment: Changed to printf "%s\n", $test; It works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Pri, `print "$test\n";` and `say $test;` are more idiomatic. No need to invoke `printf` for this.

Comment: @Pri Always put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your Perl scripts. `warnings` would have told you `Argument "-S%d" isn't numeric in printf at ...`